# PhpStorm debug console says "this view is read only"

Tags: php, console, phpstorm, xdebug

I have xdebug stop in one breakpoint and I want to test some code in console but I have a problem.

I can't write in console and when I tried to paste it says "this view is read only"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your screenshot and what you wish to do correctly ... then PhpStorm version you are using is too old.

The **Interactive Debug Console** was added in v10 while you are using v9.0.2.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/09/get-an-advantages-of-interactive-console-during-debugging-in-phpstorm-9-5-eap/

Upgrade your PhpStorm to the latest version -- which is 2017.1.2 right now.

Answer (score 62):

I had the same issue with log files. Disabling all log highlight plugins (i.e. Ideolog) fixed it. They weren't highlighting anything anyway except scrollbar in green color.
Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: great! for me it was "Ideolog" plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled that silly plugin and I can edit log file again

Comment: Thanks! It was due to mentioned plugin

Comment: I restarted my Phpstorm, and ibus both. Only this helped. Thanks.

Comment: great! for me it was "Ideolog" plugin too

Comment: Works like a charm, wasn't having highlighting at all with Ideolog, and when disabling it, I got some + I can remove all content of file :) thanks

Comment: What was strange for me is that I was able to do a global search and replace in the file just fine. But then when I tried to type in the exact same file buffer, I got the "readonly" error.

Comment: I was also using Ideolog and there's a setting that says "Allow editing for files under X kb" and X is configurable. I just bumped that up to 1024kb and was able to edit without having to disable the plugin completely.

Comment: Same as expected: Disabling "Ideolog" plugin worked for me too. Thanks.

Comment: Same, "Ideolog" plugin was the cause...

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this can happen for the log file that is too large. PhpStorm disables the possibility of editing it and adds “this view is read only” message.

Comment: Exactly my case, thanks!

Comment: I Just open logs file in other text editor and delete the logs. This method is working! Thanks!